# Location services incorrectly reporting location to app

Tags: ios, geolocation

I am using a third party financial app on my iPhone 6, and for some technical reason my iPhone is unable to provide the app the exact location. It always shows that I am not in the UK, because in order to run the App the location must be United Kingdom.

I reset my router and tried with a different Wi-Fi but it's still not working.

Comment: Your title should be relevant to the actual problem you are facing. A nondescript title obfuscates the content of the question. I've edited the title to be more specific but feel free to edit further.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, geolocation is not related to the WiFi you are using.

Then, check in your iPhone *settings* if the **Location Services** (inside *Privacy*) are **On** (therefore enabled) for your particular App.